# Perl: Capture incorrect subroutine module names at check syntax?

Tags: perl, syntax

If I have a perl module such as:

```
package mytest;
use base 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = qw(mysub);

sub mysub
{
 print "foo";
}
1;
```

How can I use `perl -c` (syntax check) to capture when the code has typos in the function names? Currently I have tried this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use mytest;

&mysub();
&mysup(); # <-- Run time crash that is not captured with perl -c myfile.pl
mysup(); # <-- Also not captured with perl -c myfile.pl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that.

The `-c` option checks only that the *syntax* of the Perl file is correct. A call of a non-existent subroutine is a *semantic* error, and because a Perl subroutine can be defined at any point during run time, it can be diagnosed only when an attempt is made to call a subroutine.

Incidentally, global identifiers like package names should be *capitalised*, so your package should be called `Mytest` and the source should be in `Mytest.pm`.

Also, it is bad practice to call subroutines using the ampersand `&` prefix. Your main program should look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mytest;

mysub();
mysup();
mysup();
```

Comment: Re: "global identifiers like package names should be capitalised", because all lowercase names 1) indicate a pragma and 2) are reserved for use by Perl.

Comment: Re "it is bad practice to call subroutines using the ampersand `&` prefix", because it actually does something, and you don't mean to do it.